# Breeze 1.4.0 navigation property not working

Tags: breeze

I've been trying to get this to work for quite a while now and still no success...

I have the following model:

```
public class Master
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Version { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Detail> DetailsList { get; set; }
}

public class Detail
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

My controller looks like this:

```
...
[HttpGet]
public string Metadata()
{
    return _contextProvider.Metadata();
}


[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<Master> Masters()
{
   return _contextProvider.Context.Masters.Include("DetailsList");
}
...
```

On the client side I have the query like this:

```
...
var query = EntityQuery.from('Masters').expand("DetailsList");

return manager.executeQuery(query)
    .then(querySucceeded)
    .fail(queryFailed);

function querySucceeded(data) {
    var master = data.results[0];

    if (masterObservable) {
        masterObservable(master);
    }
}
...
```

The issue I'm having is that the DetailsList property does not exist in the master object even though I can see it in the JSON coming back from the server.
If I set hasServerMetadata: true in breeze.DataService the object will have the property but obviously it no longer uses the Metadata.
This code used to work just fine in version 1.1.3 but since I upgraded to 1.4.0 it no longer works. I tried 1.4.1 as well with no luck.
I'm assuming it has something to do with the metadata but I just cannot figure out what am I missing to get it to work again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must define a foreign key in the Detail entity as Breeze associations require foreign keys:

```
public class Detail
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }

    public int MasterId { get; set; }
    public Master Master { get; set; }
}
```

You can find additional information about associations at http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/navigation-properties.

Comment: Thank you. This worked. I added before the Master reference into the Detail class but I was missing MasterId.